# Force page count except last page

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

Maybe it's an easy question and hope someone can help me.

Currently, I have used my PDF to begin every chapter on an odd page. by using the code

`<xsl: attribute-set name = "__ force__page__count">` in my *commons-attr.xsl* file

The result is that there are always an even number of pages in my PDF.

But how do I get it now that if my PDF has an odd number of pages that this action is not added on the last page
I thought doing like the code below will not help

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="__force__page__count">
        <xsl:attribute name="force-page-count">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="(position() = last())"> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="'no-force'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'even'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
```

Comment: The `<xsl:when>` and `<xsl:otherwise>` conditions are both assigning a value of `even` to the attribute `force-page-count`. Is that a typo in the code?

Comment: The two conditions must be set on "even". i just checked it to be sure of my case. If i change one of the two to "odd" the blank pages will disappear.

Now i must find the trick that when the PDF has a nicely filled in last page that I don't get an blank page after it. I hoped to do that with "!=last()" as you can see in my code above.

Comment: To clarify: you want all page-sequences to end on even, except the last one?

Comment: Thanks for your respond.
@Hebbes,  Almost there, All page-sequences starts on a odd page or must be forced to start on a odd page. after testing, this result was good but now   i was getting an (unwanted) blank page as a last page. And i don't need that blank page

Comment: Can you add an overview of your XML structure? If the structure is different from what I expect, the position() test won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problems start with `<xsl:when test="name(/*) = 'bookmap' != last()">`. You're testing whether the name of a node is unequal to last(). 
You need something like  `<xsl:when test="(position() != last()) and (name(/*) = 'bookmap')">`

Or `position() != last()` may be sufficient, I'd expect this attribute set to be called only at the start of a chapter/page-sequence, so your `bookmap` test may not be necessary. I'm not familiar with the framework you're using.

Of course, whether this works, depends on the structure of the XML. If your XML has one node for each chapter, and the attribute-set is called when processing this chapter node, then it should work.

If the attribute-set is called from somewhere else, or the structure is different, the position() test wont give the expected result.

And you currently have a test that tries to match every chapter except the last one, so if the test works, your 'otherwise' will only be called for the last chapter. A better way to structure the `xsl:choose` is to put the exceptions in the xsl:when statement:

```
<xsl:when test="position() = last()"> -match only the last chapter here-
    <xsl:value-of select="'no-force'"/>
```

and for the `xsl:otherwise`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="'even'"/>
```

In XSL-FO, the page count is controlled by the [force-page-count](http://www.datypic.com/sc/fo11/a-force-page-count-1.html) attribute. One of the possible values is `no-force`, this has the effect you want: no pages are added.
The value 'odd' forces the page-sequence to have an odd number of pages (and will add empty pages to achieve this).

Comment: After testing it with "no-force" all the blank pages are gone that's not what i need. but thanks for sharing

Comment: If you changed just the `otherwise` condition to no-force and all page-sequences change, that's a sign the `xsl:when` test isn't working.

Comment: correctly said. i maked a mistake in the code now it is good again. only the `otherwise` is no-force is not working.

Comment: Your anwser is helping me. it is given no result for so far. I must do some several test with this as fundation

Current code

`<xsl:attribute-set name="__force__page__count">
        <xsl:attribute name="force-page-count">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(position() = last())">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'no-force'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'even'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>`

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `force-page-count` and instead use `initial-page-number="auto-odd"`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#initial-page-number

When you omit `force-page-count`, its default value of `auto` plays well with `initial-page-number`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#force-page-count

Answer (score 0):

Hi all we  did several tests and we came out. Hereby the code

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="__force__page__count">
        <xsl:attribute name="force-page-count">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[(contains(@class, 'topic/topic'))] and not(ancestor::*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')])">
            <!--   <xsl:when test="$mirror-page-margins">-->
                    <xsl:value-of select="'end-on-even'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:when test="not(following-sibling::*[(contains(@class, 'topic/topic'))])">                    
                    <xsl:value-of select="'auto'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'auto'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
```

Thank you all for sharing your wisdom.